# iTunesConnect: How can I add meta data for specific Apple Store page? I need English (New Zealand)

Tags: localization, app-store-connect

How can I add meta data for the New Zealand apple store from iTunes Connect page when submitting an app for review? The new images I have include the New Zealand flag so I can't use English (U.K.) or English (Australia) for localisation. The content also includes the New Zealand taxation office name so I can't use the content English (Australia). So, I need something like English (New Zealand) in localisation settings.

[image]

In my current Xcode Settings I only use a single English localisation file by default and in iTunes page I can see all English(x) localisations except New Zealand. So I don't think this is Xcode setup related. Could you please give me some advice?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I created a support request yesterday and today Apple said a localisation item doesn't represent a region/country. So the answer is, it is not possible.